# How to iterate 2 data of 2-dimensional arrays with zip in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have 2 data (datatrain and datatest) with id, letter, and answer as the columns:

```
import pandas as pd

datatrain = pd.DataFrame([[1,'A','Yes'],[2,'B','No'],[3,'C','Yes'],[4,'A','No'],[5,'B','Yes']], columns=['id','letter','answer'])
datatest = pd.DataFrame([[1,'B',''],[2,'B',''],[3,'B','']], columns=['id','letter','answer'])
```

When I iterate them with zip...

```
for (no_train, data_train), (no_test, data_test) in zip(datatrain.groupby('letter'),datatest.groupby('letter')):
    print(data_train.values)
    print(data_test.values)
    // bnb.fit(data_train['id','letter'], data_train['answer'])
    // pred = bnb.predict(data_test['id','letter'])
```

The print(data_test.values) work as intended, but I'll only get the first letter of groupby on print(data_train.values), I want to print all groupby letters of data_train.

Result of print(data_train.values):

```
[[1,'A','Yes']
 [4,'A','No']]
```

Expected result of print(data_train.values):

```
[[1,'A','Yes']
 [4,'A','No']]
[[2,'B','No']
 [5,'B','Yes']]
[[3,'C','Yes']]
```

How do I iterate 2 data of 2-dimensional arrays with zip? I want to implement Naive Bayes classifier at the same time so I can't separate datatrain and datatest in different loops or nest datatest loop inside of datatrain loop

Comment: I edited my question many times, should I delete and make a new question instead?

Comment: Your data in the 2nd dimension is of different types.  Are you sure you wish to iterate through it?  I would understand the question if the 2nd dimension was data of the same time but why would you want to do it if it is of different types?

Comment: Umm I not sure what do you mean by type? I want to add another loop inside the existing loop to be able to print 2-dimension array but I don't know how to add it

Comment: In the second dimension, you have an int, a char and a string - all are different types.  If you wish to iterate through, then you will need to know the the type you are referring to at each index.  In that case, you may as well just index them directly instead of iterating.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all 3 letter types in *data_train*, make sure you have all those 3 types in 
*datatest*.

for example, this should give your expected result

```
import pandas as pd

datatrain = pd.DataFrame([[1,'A','Yes'],[2,'B','No'],[3,'C','Yes'],[4,'A','No'],[5,'B','Yes']], columns=['id','letter','answer'])

datatest = pd.DataFrame([[1,'B','xx'],[2,'B','xx'],[3,'B','xx'], [3,'A','yy'], [3,'C','yy']], columns=['id','letter','answer'])


for (no_train, data_train), (no_test, data_test) in zip(datatrain.groupby('letter'), datatest.groupby('letter')):
    print(data_train.values)
```

Result:

```
[[1 'A' 'Yes']
 [4 'A' 'No']]
[[2 'B' 'No']
 [5 'B' 'Yes']]
[[3 'C' 'Yes']]
```

this happens because of the way [zip()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) works.